# Functional component does not work when importing it in test

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I have a functional component `Foo.js` that looks like this:

```
const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <View></View>
  )
}
export default Foo
```

This component **works fine when rendering it in the app**.

---

The **issue is when trying to test** the component like this:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import Foo from './Foo'
test('testing', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<Foo />)  <--- Error occurs
})
```

An **error occurs** when running this test (when calling `renderer.create`), saying:
`Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.`

---

The strange thing is that **the test passes** without any error **if I put the component inside the test file**:

```
const Foo = () => {
  return (
      <View></View>
  )
}
test('testing', () => {
  const component = renderer.create(<Foo />)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the cause for this was that the exported component got mocked, due to that I had automock set to true in my jest config.

Changing this in `jest.config.js`:

```
automock: true
```

Into this:

```
automock: false
```

Resolves the issue.

---

**Question**: Why is the automocked component not returning anything? Could that be solved in some way so that it would work having automock set to true?